# Mask Phone number with brackets and spaces Java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have a method for the phone number masking. I need to replace all digits with stars except the last 4. 
Sample inputs would be: ***+91 (333) 444-5678*** and ***+1(333) 456-7890***. Outputs should look this way:

[image]

But my output actually looks like this:

[image]

So here is my code:

```
public static String maskPhoneNumber(String inputPhoneNum){
        return inputPhoneNum.replaceAll("\\(", "-")
                .replaceAll("\\)", "-")
                .replaceAll(" ", "-")
                .replaceAll("\\d(?=(?:\\D*\\d){4})", "*");
    }
```

My method works with different number of digits in country codes, but it breaks in cases when instead of a space between digits there are brackets near the country code (triad after it).
I would be grateful for some hints on how I can improve my approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you replace each individual space, `(` and `)` with a `-`. You need to replace all consecutive occurrences with 1 hyphen.

Use

```
public static String maskPhoneNumber(String inputPhoneNum){
    return inputPhoneNum.replaceAll("[()\\s]+", "-")
            .replaceAll("\\d(?=(?:\\D*\\d){4})", "*");
}
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/5FY88o).

The `+91 (333) 444-5678` turns into `+**-***-***-5678` and `+1(333) 456-7890` turns into `+*-***-***-7890`.

The `[()\s]+` pattern matches 1 or more (`+`) consecutive `(`, `)` or whitespace chars. See [the "normalization" step regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/422y54/2) and the [final step demo](https://regex101.com/r/422y54/4).

Comment: But what about the case when there is no country code? It is a possible one. For example, for (333)456-7890 this regex will put a dash in the beginning.

Comment: @Cassie: What is the expected result for `(333)456-7890`? `***-***-7890`? Check [this updated Java demo](https://ideone.com/7cCbWw).

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot.

Comment: @Eugene If you mean the `appendReplacement`, it is old as the world, and yes, we could revamp the current OP solution to use that method, but it is not really helpful here and might turn out even more "tricky". See, your solution does not provide the expected result.

Comment: @Eugene I did not downvote it, just note that if you want to solve it with 1 regex, it will be quite lengthy, with some alternations and capturing groups. Might not be worth a candle.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I absolutely don't want to do it in a single regex - just wanted to show that there is support in the language for this, nothing else. hey, I even up-voted your answer. thx for the correction btw

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated API in the language itself for that (in the form of `appendReplacement`)

```
    String test = "+91 (333) 444-5678";
    test = test.replaceAll("[()\\s]+", "-");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?!\\d*$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // +**-***-***-5678

    for (; m.find();) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().replaceAll(".", "*"));
    }

    m.appendTail(sb);

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```